# I need to prove that $\hat\theta=\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ is a mean square consistent estimator for $\theta$

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimators, consistency

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ a i.i.d from a population with distribution $U[0,\theta]$, i.e.,

$f_{X_i}(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}g_{[0,\theta]}(x)$, for $i=1, \ldots, n$

where

\begin{align}
g_{[0,\theta]}(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & x \in [0, \theta], \\
0 & x \notin [0, \theta]. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

How to prove that $\hat\theta = \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ is a root mean square consistent estimator for $\theta$?

I know that an estimator $\hat\theta_n$ is consistent in root mean square if it fulfills that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}MSE(\hat\theta_n)=0.$$

with $MSE(\hat\theta_n)=E[(\hat\theta_n-\theta)^2]=\operatorname{Var}(\hat\theta_n)+(E(\hat\theta_n)-\theta)^2$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to show consistency proving that $E(\hat\theta)=\theta$ and $Var(\hat\theta)=0$ but I'm not sure if that's enough to prove root mean square consistency

Comment: @WillowDouglas What you "tried to show" is impossible to hold (which would imply $\hat{\theta} \equiv \theta$).  The correct procedure obviously relies on "$\lim_n$".

Comment: @Zhanxiong, my guess is to find the bias from the estimator (by finding $E(\hat\theta_n)$) and $Var(\hat\theta_n)$. But first you have to find the CDF and the density function of the estimator.

Comment: @WillowDouglas Exactly, so can you find the CDF of $X_{(n)} := \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$?  It is a pretty standard result.

Comment: CDF of $\hat\theta_n$ would be :=$\frac{z^n}{\theta^n}$ and then you can easily get the pdf by computing the derivative...

Comment: @Zhanxiong I have the doubt if the CDF of $\hat\theta_n$ would be :=$\frac{x^n}{\theta^n}$ or $\frac{1}{\theta^n}$. Since $g(x)=1$ for $0<=x<=\theta$

Comment: I don't follow how the doubt arises; what's the cdf of $X$? (NB it's not $g$)

Answer (score 3):

The standard way is to find the CDF of $\hat{\theta}_n$ first, which is
\begin{align*}
F(x) := P(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{x}{\theta} = 
\frac{x^n}{\theta^n}, \; 0 \leq x \leq \theta. 
\end{align*}
This implies the PDF of $\hat{\theta}_n$ is $f(x) = nx^{n - 1}/\theta^n$ for $0 \leq  x \leq \theta$ and $0$ otherwise, whence
\begin{align*}
E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = \int_0^\theta(t - \theta)^2f(t)dt = 
\frac{n}{\theta^n}\int_0^\theta (t - \theta)^2t^{n - 1}dt. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
To evaluate the integral $(1)$, apply the variable substitution $u = t/\theta$, which transfers $(1)$ to
\begin{align*}
n\int_0^1\theta^2(1 - u)^2 u^{n - 1} du = \theta^2nB(3, n), \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where $B(a, b)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).  Since $B(a, b) = (a - 1)!(b - 1)!/(a + b - 1)!$ when $a, b$ are positive integers,  the right-hand side of $(2)$ equals to
\begin{align}
\theta^2 \frac{2n(n - 1)! }{(n + 2)!} = \frac{2\theta^2}{(n + 2)(n + 1)},
\end{align}
which converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  This shows that $\hat{\theta}_n \to \theta$ in quadratic mean.

The above method is straightforward.  However, it involves pretty heavy calculations (you may circumvent summoning the Beta function by expanding $(1 - u)^2$ then applying linearity of the integral, which requires less machinery). This motivates me to consider the following alternative solution.

First, show that $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability.  I will leave this to you as an exercise.  It is similar to finding the CDF of $\hat{\theta}_n$.

Next, for any $\epsilon \in (0, \theta)$, we have
\begin{align*}
& E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] = 
E\left[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2I_{[|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| \leq \epsilon]}(\omega)\right] + 
E\left[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2I_{[|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| > \epsilon]}(\omega)\right] \\
\leq & \epsilon^2 + 4\theta^2P[|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| > \epsilon]. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Since $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges to $\theta$ in probability, the second term in $(3)$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this implies that $E[(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)^2] \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, completing the proof.

Comment: Well if you show convergence in probability then by Vitali’s convergence theorem you have $L^p$ convergence since the sequence of random variables $\hat{\theta}_n$ is uniformly integrable (in fact, its bounded). I guess your last step is encapsulating part of the proof of that theorem.